# Eraser does only paint white color instead of alpha channel

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I need to replace all white color in my image with an alpha channel, so that the area is transparent. Normally I would just select it and then press "DEL" to remove it, but this is the result:

[image]

Why is the area replaced with white color and not with transparency?

Comment: What do you mean by alpha?

Comment: @WELZ, I mean the alpha channel (https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/alpha_channel.html)

Comment: Double click the background layer and click OK to unlock it. Now try again.

Comment: @BillyKerr, that solved it xD thx

Comment: @BillyKerr please leave that as an answer so Black can mark it solved. Otherwise this is going to get automatically bumped every so often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click the lock on your Background Layer to unlock the layer. Name it whatever you like; after that, you should be able to select the entire area of the background using <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove it from there.

Comment: Also remove white matting ;)